# How to gamma, remove, or increase of alpha channel of a strip

Tags: transparency, video-sequence-editor

I'm using a glow effect to add a outline to text. I'd like the outline to have sharp edges, but after setting all the nobs on the glow to max, the edges are still somewhat blurry.

If I could set the alpha of the strip to more than 1 that would work... but you can't. If I could add a curves modifier to the strip that would work, but you can only apply it to the R, G, or B channel, not the alpha. There's a "blend mode" "alpha clip" setting that could be used but its for materials not for video editor strips.

[Example file with outlined text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gT92jykULtNseUu1I2Ff6TRUGDe4pf8O/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: pls provide a blend file with just the text and the result you are showing in your question. thanks.